# Extract an array from a postgres json column and map it

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

```
create table test(a json);

insert into test(a) 
values('{"orders":[{"orderId":1}, {"orderId":2, "status":"done"}, {"orderId":3}]}');
```

Given the structure above, can I get an array or set of orderIds that are not 'done'?  And by that, I mean can I get the orderIds from with sql or plpgsql?

Any advice would be great!  Thank you very much!

Comment: That's not valid JSON, did you actually try inserting it? (edit: fixed it, but seriously, **test your examples**).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Once I fixed the broken JSON, this was just a `LATERAL` query to unpack the array and filter it.

```
select (x->>'orderId')::integer
from test,
     json_array_elements(a->'orders') x 
where (x ->> 'status') IS DISTINCT FROM 'done';
```

I used `IS DISTINCT FROM` so I didn't have to test for both `NULL` (no key) and `!= 'done'`.

Comment: For anyone else running into the problem, you'll need to use jsonb_array_elements on a jsonb datatype (note the extra B).